# Looking for styling width equation to scale with screen width

Tags: css

Im trying to work out a styling calc to scale the width of a column to your screen width. For instance, what im working on now is i want the following:

1920px screen width = 525px div column width

1366px screen width = 425px div column width

A reference site i've found uses this for text size: `width: (3-1) x 1.2vw + 1rem;` , i'd prefer to take that route minus the 'rem', but if anyone has a code suggestion or a reference example that could help me figure out how to do this anything would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What's wrong with taking what you came up with and tossing it in a `calc()`?

Comment: I came up with a calc that can get 530px at 1920 screen width, but when you apply that same equation to the 1366 screen width its only 376. I need it to be closer to 425.

Comment: What do you want to happen when the screen width is less than 1366px or greater than 1920px? This question is very similar to [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623375/how-to-shrink-a-from-a-max-height-to-a-min-height-over-the-size-decrease-of-the/65625585#65625585

Comment: Wy hnot show us the calculation that you did then we can see if we can improve it. Basically you've got the values of width and screensize of two simultaneous equations width=a*screensize+b from which you can find the width at any screen size.

Comment: Sure, i was trying to use `width: 13vh + 275px`
It was giving about 525 at 1920 but 450 at 1366. I need the 1366 width to yield a max of 425, but lower is ok so long as its between 400-425. Hope that helps!