# How to shrink a from a max-height to a min-height over the size decrease of the viewport width?

Tags: javascript, html, css, column-width

If I have a body element and I decrease screen size, it is a 1:1 ratio.
If I have an body tag at width 50%. its a 1:1 ratio. Every pixel decrease of the viewport directly effects the width of element.

If I have 2 Elements side by side. I want to have the first element (`.left`) start at a width of 400px, at a screen width of 1300px, but increase a total of 100px over the course of the screen increase to 1920px.
The second element (`.right`) will fill the rest of the space and decrease at the according rate of the screen +/- the current width of `.left`
`.right`
`1300px` `->` `1920px`
`400px` `->` `500px`
`.left`
`width:100%`
I know this doesnt work but this is the code I've got so far.

```css
.full{
background-color: lightblue;
width:100%;
height:50px;
}
.half{
width:50%;
height:50px;
background-color:grey;
}
#flex{
display:flex;
}
.right{
max-width:500px;
min-width:400px;
height:50px;
background-color:lightgreen;
width:70%;
}
.left{
height:50px;
background-color:lightpink;
width:30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full"></div>
<div class="half"></div>
<div id="flex">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please double-check that you worded everything correctly. You've mentioned height in the title, but not in the body. Also, in your snippet, `.right` is on the left, while `.left` is on the right. I'd love to help, but your question is too confusing to know what you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the wording in the question is what is required, i.e. the left element is to have a min value of 400px, a max value of 500px and is to increase in size from the min starting at body width 1300px and stopping at 1920px.

left therefore needs to be set to have a `min-width: 400px` and `max-width: 500px`

We need to calculate what the width will be to increase by 100px between the given start and end body width values. The formula for this is:

s + (i / d) * (a - b)

where
s = starting width of left element (400)
i = increase in left width (100)
d = difference between start and end body widths (1620)
a = actual body width now (100%)
b = starting body width (1300)

The right element is to take up the remaining space so needs to be given `flex: auto;`

In this snippet the various dimensions have been set using CSS variables so as to make it easier to change them.

```css
.full{
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
}
.half{
  width: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:grey;
}
#flex{
  display: flex;
}
.right{
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  flex: auto;
}
.left{
  height:50px;
  background-color:lightpink;

  /* SET THESE 4 VARIABLES TO WHAT YOU WANT */
  --startb: 1300; /* width of the body after which left starts to get bigger */
  --endb: 1920; /* width of the body after which left stops getting bigger */
  --startleft: 400; /* the start (hence minimum) width of the left element */
  --incw: 100; /* the increase in the left's width when have reached the end body width */
  
  /* we calculate some interim values just to make it a bit easier to see what's happening */
  --startbw: calc(var(--startb) * 1px);
  --endbw: calc(var(--endb) * 1px);
  --incb: calc(var(--endb) - var(--startb));
  --startw: calc(var(--startleft) * 1px);
  
  width: calc(var(--startw) + calc(calc(var(--incw) / var(--incb)) * calc(100% - var(--startbw))));
  min-width: var(--startw);
  max-width: calc(var(--startw) + calc(var(--incw) * 1px));
}
```

```html
<div class="full"></div>
<div class="half"></div>
<div id="flex">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```